Generating multiple EmbeddedChart in Appscript based on a filter
Based on the sheet here, I want to be able to generate a line graph for every Breakdown in the sheet.
Using the code below, I was able to  list and split the rows I want into tuples and create a DataTable but the Embedded chart requires a range.
How do I adjust the below to allow me to paste the line chart in the sheet (and then link it to slides) using a range based on the unique Breakdowns in the data.
function getCols(arr,cols) {
  return arr.map(row =>
    row.filter((_,i) => cols.includes(++i)))
}

function createLineChartsForBreakdowns() {
  var sheetId = '1o7YMSSRu3XIraPEAad0I0Q0fNUtmEKDlJt5zSJlKBgM'; // Replace with your sheet ID
  var sheetName = 'testSheet'; // Replace with your sheet name
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  var breakdowns = [];
  var breakdownData = {};
  var breakdownDataTable = {};
  
  // Get unique breakdown values and store data for each breakdown
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var breakdown = data[i][0];
    
    if (!breakdowns.includes(breakdown)) {
      breakdowns.push(breakdown);
      breakdownData[breakdown] = (getCols(data.filter(function (row) {
        return row[0] == breakdown
  }),[2,3])); 

  }
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < breakdowns.length; k++) {
    Logger.log(breakdownData[breakdowns[k]])
    breakdownDataTable[breakdowns[k]] = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "X")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Y")
    for (var l =0; l<breakdownData[breakdowns[k]].length; l++)
    breakdownDataTable[breakdowns[k]]
    .addRow(breakdownData[breakdowns[k]][l])
    .build();
  }
  Logger.log(breakdown)
  Logger.log(breakdownData[breakdown])
  Logger.log(breakdownDataTable[breakdown])
  
  // Create a separate line chart for every breakdown
  var charts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < breakdowns.length; i++) {
    var breakdown = breakdowns[i];
    var title = breakdown + ' Line Chart';
    
     var chart = sheet.newChart().asLineChart()
      .setTitle(title)
      .setXAxisTitle('X')
      .setYAxisTitle('Y')
      //.setDimensions(600, 500)
      .setCurveStyle(Charts.CurveStyle.SMOOTH)
      .setPointStyle(Charts.PointStyle.MEDIUM)
      //.setDataTable(breakdownDataTable[breakdown])
      .build();
      
  
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  }
  
}

Thank you!

By using the form of the function getRange where you pass the start row and end dow, you can get what you need.
getRange(sheetName.concat("!B",breakdownData[breakdown]["start"],":C",breakdownData[breakdown]["end"]));

